# How to make changes to the code inside a Docker Container?

Tags: node.js, docker

I'm completely new to Docker and Containers. I'm also new to the entire VM concepts.

I understand that VM and Dockers are a way to make all the dependencies of an application to be available as a single component that you can easily deploy on clouds that support them.

I installed Docker on my local machine (an Ubuntu) and I used [used this guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/) to download and run the Node Official Image.

What I need to know now is how do I make code changes for the files inside of Docker? I made changes to the 'server.js' inside the app and when I navigate to `http://locahost:49160` the browser still shows the output from the old `server.js`. I restarted the container and yet I get the same old output.

I see that I can commit changes and make a new image. But then, isn't the old image completely useless?

Or am I *not at all* understanding how things with Docker work?

Comment: I don't use docker, but when I make changes in my containers they persist.

Comment: Oh.. is the problem with starting the nodejs server again? Because I tried that and I failed.

Comment: Mounting as a volume seemed like the easiest option during development.

Comment: Mount volumes with the `-v` command. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#volume-shared-filesystems

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could make changes inside an container and could even commit these changes to the original image or create a new image as well as.

But I recommend you to create a new images or tags.

Review the [guide](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/). When you want to make a change on `server.js`, let do it but build a new image for it also. Don't forget to add a tag (`test1`).

Example, `docker build -t <your username>/node-web-app:test1 .`

Then you could run the new image with `docker run -p 49160:8080 -d <your username>/node-web-app:test1`

Comment: Okay, I'll test this and let you know.

Comment: Building the new image works. How frequently should the images be built?

Comment: Everytime you make edits in your code and want to deploy it.

Comment: @lorenzvth7 is right. If you work on an open source, try to integrate the GitHub and Docker Hub. Docker Hub can help to build your image automatically whenever you make a change on GitHub repo.

Comment: okay. But I'm not working on open source. I am just using Docker so it's easy to scale when deployed.

Answer (score 3):

In your case. You'll probably need to rebuild your image:

```
docker build -t my-new-image .
```

You made an edit to your `server.js` which is copied inside your image/container. The old image will be useless indeed. You'll need to start a new container with `docker run` after the build.

In some cases it's possible to mount your code/data to your docker container with `docker run -v my-local-volume:/volume-in container ...`

When you make edits to your code on your local machine it will be updated inside your container automatically. Without updating the image or restarting the container. But in your case your copying the code inside your application with the `COPY` command of the dockerfile.

Comment: Is there a way to constantly copy the code without doing it manually every time?

Comment: I don't know nodejs that good. But I think the 'issue' is the fact that the npm install is done inside the image (which is probably dependent of your package.json -> server.js). So if what maybe could be a solution is creating a startup.sh script which will perform the npm install + npm start at container startup (docker run with mounting your code) instead of doing this inside the image.